# Is there a Scala like Clojurescript? aka Integrated Scala Single Page Application

Tags: scala, groovy, clojure, clojurescript, single-page-application

So **[ClojureScript One](http://clojurescriptone.com/index.html)** is rather incredible looking! You can make updates with your REPL in real time to a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

So something like this is rather impossible in Java where you don't have a REPL but it seems very possible in something like Groovy or Scala. I'm sort of a Lisp bigot (I really shouldn't be but oh well) and wondering if there is a Scala or Groovy like Clojurescript?

**Update:**
In theory it looks like one could wrap Scala/Groovy around Java's **[ItsNat](http://itsnat.sourceforge.net/index.php?_page=overview)**. However I have some doubts about that project given it hasn't been updated since 2011 (also they have they ugliest website.. its like they tried to make it ugly). The license is also rather restrictive.

Comment: I have only seen this proof-of-concept, but there might be other projects: http://www.j2js.com/scala-demo/index.html

Comment: And this project, which seems to be abandoned: https://github.com/alvaroc1/s2js

Comment: License was made more open(GNU Lesser General Public License v3), previous was (AGPL v 3)

Comment: I'd not bother about ItsNat website, rather, head over here: http://www.innowhere.com:8080/itsnat/feashow_servlet?itsnat_doc_name=feashow.main

Comment: Adam, I'm the author of ItsNat, I'm not interested on "web beauty" I'm more interested on "engineering beauty", if you don't understand the difference ItsNat is not for you. Web beauty is up you, this is the conceptual background of ItsNat

Comment: @jmarranz while I agree in theory ... I disagree in practice. We live in a shallow world and sex sales. IMHO One of the reasons Ruby on Rails took off is the idea I'm going to get something that doesn't look like #$@#$ out of the box. With things like Bootstrap out there this should not be hard and in fact is good engineering.

Comment: ItsNat is a low level framework, there is no "beauty out of the box", you can use any CSS framework and any HTML layout, furthermore, you can clone any paged web site UI and make it single page, for instance this one: http://www.innowhere.com:8080/insites/

Answer (score 5):

Try http://www.scala-js.org/ a A Scala to JavaScript compiler

Answer (score 2):

There's [js-scala](https://github.com/js-scala/js-scala), but it seems to be quite experimental at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

ItsNat has come to quit a stable stage, this is why it is inactive. Of course new features and more browser support and testing can be leveraged, but so far, we've had a great experience with ItsNat. We've been with ItsNat since version 0.7 and had very (2) issues, that too, quite rare ones.

If you'd like working examples, I'd be glad to show you as our project is open sourced :-)

Works well with both SEO and SPI.

[Demo](http://www.innowhere.com/itsnat/feashow_servlet?itsnat_doc_name=feashow.main)

Comment: BTW, if you are planning to scale out, then be sure to check their "Stateless" modes before starting your designs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for SPA [scala-gwt](http://scalagwt.github.com/). Or you are looking for scala-to-javascript compiler?

Comment: I'm looking for a Scala [Clojurescript One](http://clojurescriptone.com/). Seeing how "Clojurescript One" works it would probably need a *scala-to-javascript* compiler. GWT in my mind is to heavy handed and component/widget based. Clojurescript One is like JQuery in the backend that gets applied to the frontend seemlessly. BTW I didn't -1 you.

Comment: Downvoted, cause scala-gwt is not direct analog to clojurescript, despite the ability to convert scala code to javascript